# Enable debugging without relaunching app in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

This is, by far, the most missed feature for me.

When using eclipse, in the devices view I was able to enable debug for specific app without relaunching.

I can't find such a feature in Android Studio. Relaunching the app all over in the debug mode is real pain. Is there a way to enable it in the middle of the process like it is possible in eclipse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an icon for that on the main toolbar which is called **Attach debugger to Android process** (highlighted in red in the image below):

[image: Android Studio Toolbar]

The same option can also be found on the `Run` menu.

Once you click this, a list of processes from attached devices will be displayed. Simply choose the one you want to debug and you're set :)